# Java EE 6 and Certutil

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, certificate, nss

I have installed Java EE 6 with GlassfishV3. I want to use NSS tools to manage the security of the server, i.e generating certificates using certutil. However I can't find the NSS library and tools in Glassfish. On the other hand, I read the documentations of Java EE 6 and it says that it still supports NSS!

Does anybody know about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one such tool in linux under /usr/bin/certutil. Just add a certificate to the database so you could list certificates after that. To add a certificate issued by a trusted CA just execute this command in linux:

```
$ sudo certutil -A -n ServerCert -t "P,u,u" -d /path/to/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/ directory -i  /path/to/your/server-cert.pem
```

Now to get a list of installed certificates issue a command like this:

```
$ sudo certutil -L -d /path/to/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/
```